# Encourage Admob clicks violates the TOS?

Tags: java, android, admob

I have a little game published in Android Market. I'm considering implementing a mechanism for award the clicks over the ads with in-game points, trying to detect them using the Adlistener class provided by Admob.

Doing that would violate the terms of service Admob or any other rule of Android Market?

I have read the TOS and don't see this point explicitly stated. The point where these things are treated is this:

> User shall not, and shall not authorize or encourage any third party to generate fraudulent impressions of or fraudulent clicks on any advertisement, including but not limited to, through repeated manual clicks, the use of robots or other automated query tools and/or computer generated search requests, and/or the fraudulent use of other search engine optimization services and/or software

So the question is, does encourage the clicks convert them into fraudulent clicks?

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

Think of it this way, if you were an advertiser would you want people clicking on your ad because "they were generally interested in your product or service" or "because they wanted a reward in the game".

Users who click on the ads because they just want a reward in the game have less interest in the ad and may have no interest at all yet the advertiser is still paying for these clicks from these uninterested users.

While it might not be against the TOS right now. I'm sure Admob would consider making it against the TOS if advertisers complained and if your game becomes popular at least a few Admob advertisers would probably be playing and potentially complaining.

Answer (score 6):

I suspect it would depend almost entirely upon whether or not you then show the user the advert upon which they clicked. If it were my TOS i would would ban you simply because of the "motivation factor".

People are paying Google to show ads to people who are interested in their product and service and therefore click on the ad. You are repurposing the ad under the guise of a different motivation for your own reward and not the reward of the advertiser who is paying for the ad.

So basically you're ripping off the advertiser. I would not be happy to learn that i had paid as an advertiser to have someone, completely disconnected from my service or product, score a point in a game.

I'd also suggest that the passage of the TOS you have quoted is implicitly explicit about what you're comtemplating doing.

Answer (score 3):

Morally despicable, certainly.  I doubt your CTR would jump so significantly that it would raise questions.

Comment: +1 for being refreshingly certain about what's morally despicable and then sugggesting he might get away with it.

Comment: I guess its like the saying "Nothing's illegal until you get caught"

Comment: Hahaha, trying to be helpful... Next stop for me: evil dictator?